# Google App Engine local instance started from Eclipse does not stop

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently started building applications on Google App Engine. I use an Eclipse plugin to start and stop the server and deploy applications to run on Google App Engine.

I had created a new project and tried to stop and start it as suggested in the tutorials and in Stack Overflow. My old project is still running and hitting the data source successfully. I even removed the old projects from my Eclipse workspace and tried a fresh deploy of the new project with no luck.

How do I stop the server (the RED dot in my Eclipse has no effect)? Is uninstalling the App Engine the only solution?

Comment: I even tried shutting down my eclipse and had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the server, a new Java process is started.  You can find and kill it independently of Eclipse.

Comment: That's the only way I can stop it :-(

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this problem and found the solution at [Stop or restart a previously started Google App Engine local server in Eclipse](http://www.hoverdroids.com/errors/google-app-engine/stop-or-restart-a-previously-started-google-app-engine-local-server-in-eclipse/)

Just in case the link breaks, the key steps are:

1. In Eclipse, find the Eclipse Console view (looks like below).
   [image]
2. Select the arrow next to the small computer and find the server's name
3. Select the red square to stop the server
4. Go to http://localhost:8888 to see if the page is still showing (it shouldn't be)
5. If you are visiting something like http://yourAppId.appspot.com and the server is still running, that's because it's still deployed on App Engine, not locally. In this case, go to Google Developer's Console and stop the service there

Answer (score 0):

The server can be stopped by clicking red square icon in the console window. If this icon is missing or disabled, you may see wrong console window. You must select the javaw console using the drop-down button on the far right of the console window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run/Debug Configurations -> *Select your project configuration* -> Common tab -> Uncheck "Launch in background"

Now, when you terminate the server on Server's console, it will stops the server.